# How to run .hex file in mac to test atmega8 board

Tags: macos, bootloader, atmega

In windows i create a new project in AVRStudio and compile the code. Which than gives me the .hex file that i can run on Bootloader.exe that i have after compilatioin. But in Mac it doesn't seem to work. I compiled the code which then gives me the .hex file. But how to test it on Mac? I followed the step below as mentioned on this site: http://www.obdev.at/products/crosspack/index.html

```
bash$ cd Desktop
bash$ avr-project Demo
bash$ cd Demo
bash$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 cs  cs  102 Nov 22 18:29 Demo.xcodeproj
drwxr-xr-x   4 cs  cs  136 Nov 22 18:29 firmware
bash$ cd firmware
bash$ ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r--   1 cs  cs  4139 Nov 22 18:29 Makefile
-rw-r--r--   1 cs  cs   348 Nov 22 18:29 main.c
bash$ make
avr-gcc -Wall -Os -DF_CPU=8000000 -mmcu=atmega8 -c main.c -o main.o
avr-gcc -Wall -Os -DF_CPU=8000000 -mmcu=atmega8 -o main.elf main.o
rm -f main.hex
avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex main.elf main.hex
```

after that i had to run this command: 
    bash$ make flash

but it says :

```
=avrdude  -p atmega8 -U flash:w:main.hex:i

avrdude: no programmer has been specified on the command line or the config file
     Specify a programmer using the -c option and try again

make: *** [flash] Error 1
```

How to fix it? Please treat me as a Newbie i know nothing about compiling bootloaders and stuff like that. Explain me in real easy steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line (with avrdude...) should write (:w:) in the flash memory (flash:) of an ATMega8 (-p atmega8) the file main.hex, which is written using the Intel format (:i). In order to really upload this program, you must use a programmer, between the microcontroller and the computer. Also, you must tell avrdude what this programmer is, using the -c option, followed by the name of the programmer (to know exactly what the name is, enter "avrdude -c" and it will display all the programmer supported by avrdude). So, if you want to upload, modify the Makefile, search the line "avrdude -p atmega8 -U flash:w:main.hex:i" and add "-c ". It should work now